# iTunes help switching songs from one user to another

Tags: itunes, music, data-transfer

I'm sharing a computer with my sister and she has her iTunes completely disorganized. I created my own user account on the computer, and am wondering how I can move the music from the iTunes to my user account. I go to file, library, export library and save the file but that's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Home > Music and copy the "iTunes" folder to an external drive.

If you don't have an external drive big enough, you can move it to Macintosh HD > Users > (Your User Name) > Public > Dropbox. (You can copy it directly to your music file from another user, as those folders are only editable when you are in your account).

Login to your user, and move the "iTunes" folder from wherever it is to Home > Music. Open iTunes: your sister's library should be loaded.

PSS: I by no means am advocating the copy of copyrighted content with this post. I imply your music is legally downloaded, and you are moving the library with the intent of organizing it and not duplicating it in any way. Don't do illegal stuff!

Answer (score 0):

I would copy the files over using external media (hard drive, flash drive, etc.).